# How to pause the process until the method call?

Tags: c#, events, console

I have a console app, its run like windows app (background), but when i start app , its closed in 1 sec. I have System event SessionEnding, how to pause app to moment when this event will be called?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new SessionEndingEventHandler(Session_Ending);}

static void Session_Ending(object sender,SessionEndingEventArgs e)
    {
         switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionEndReasons.Logoff: { Add_Log(DataCombine(0, "LogOut")); q = SendData(DataCombine(1, "LogOut")); Check(q); break; }
            case SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown: { Add_Log(DataCombine(0, "ShutDown")); q = SendData(DataCombine(1, "ShutDown")); Check(q); break; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Or, if you need a message loop:

```
Application.Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, You may execute your program with the "*Start Without Debugging*" option or implement a `Console.ReadLine()` statement at the end of your method then your program will wait for the user's input to then terminate.

Comment: Console.ReadLine() not work cause app start in window mod (background app)